# SQL Server 2005 Express - generate script to create VIEW based on relational tables?

Tags: view, foreign-keys, primary-key, sql-server-2005-express

Is there a way in SQL Server 2005 Express to generate a script that would create a VIEW based on tables primary/foreign key relationships?

I have multiple databases with thousands of tables, and its very time consuming to look at the "table dependencies" and try to JOIN data in the query window.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Query return Create statement for tables, but you must first note that:
1. only works for 1 column foreign key references
2. has not been tested for sql server express 2005, but works fine for Sql server 2005

```
create function dbo.func59C217D64BC54EA0B841BF1AB43D9398(@table1 nvarchar(1000), @table2 nvarchar(1000))
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = ''
select @sql = @sql + dr + '.[' +cc +'] AS ['+ cc+ ISNULL(rr,'') + '],'
from (
select column_name cc,
dr = case when table_schema + '.' +table_name = @table1 then 'a' else 'b' end,
cast(NULLIF(row_number() over (partition by column_name order by table_name),1) as nvarchar) rr
 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_schema + '.' +table_name in
(@table1,@table2)
) i

return substring(@sql,1,len(@sql) - 1)
end


GO
select cast(
'CREATE VIEW ['+r.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA+'].[vw' +cp.TABLE_NAME+cf.TABLE_NAME+ ']
AS SELECT '+dbo.func59C217D64BC54EA0B841BF1AB43D9398(cp.TABLE_SCHEMA+'.' +cp.TABLE_NAME,cf.TABLE_SCHEMA+ '.' +cf.TABLE_NAME)+' FROM ['+cp.TABLE_SCHEMA+'].['+cp.TABLE_NAME+'] AS a
JOIN ['+cf.TABLE_SCHEMA+'].['+cf.TABLE_NAME +'] AS b
ON a.['+cp.COLUMN_NAME+'] = b.['+cf.COLUMN_NAME +']' as ntext) as sql
 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS r
 JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cf ON r.CONSTRAINT_NAME = cf.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
 JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cp ON r.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = cP.CONSTRAINT_NAME 


GO
DROP function dbo.func59C217D64BC54EA0B841BF1AB43D9398
```

hope I helped, or at least make you started